# How to Link Custom Android App to a Static IP PC

Tags: android-studio

I am working on a prototype android app that will draw data from a remote server.

I have a number of sensors connected to my PC that are constantly updating cells in an Excel file. I am trying to build an Android app that will remotely connect to my PC and display these values on users' cell phones.

Umm... I don't really know here to start with it.

The actual result is that users with connection to the internet will be able to open the app and see the values taken from the Excel file on my computer.

Comment: You are going to need to select a common method of data access, the most basic would be to use HTTP, almost every PC can become a web server, and Android probably has many forms of HTTP-based data access. In that context, using an IP address should be easy (although administratively it isn't the best approach, try not to become wedded to it.)

Answer (score 0):

i recommend you use StringRequest to connect an Apache server with PHP, u can use XAMPP, then u can send a Request Method POST, take the request and return the data that u want to show in android, after this u can use a recycler view to inflate the data.

Comment: OK, let's sea if I am getting this right. So I am running Apache Server with PHP on my desktop, use XAMPP to (err..... get the data from Excel?), then send the Reqest method POST from the Android App, which should make the data appear in the ANdroid Ap and then show it. Anything right?

Comment: OK, correction. So I am running Apache Server with PHP on my desktop, the XAMPP version. I send a Reqest method POST from the Android App, which should allow me to receive the data in the Android App. Then I show it to the userz. Anything right?